# How to debug code while using my browser on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I cannot debug Laravel via PhpStorm and Xdebug.

When I try to debug a single file via PhpStorm, it works fine, but when I set a breakpoint and try it on the browser, it doesn't work.

PhpStorm waits for incoming connection with ide key and it stops there.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Maybe some logs?

Comment: 2 sentence 19 words - does not a good question make

Comment: Im not getting logs at all. Just stucked. When I debug a single file it works perfect but when I try to debug laravel app via web application it stuck on waiting for incoming connection

Comment: Collect xdebug logs for such unsuccessful session and share here: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: As I understand, he wants to debug his code on browser but doesn't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow that I've set:

1. Use something like [Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc).
2. Configure it to use PhpStorm IDE Key.

When you want to debug:

1. Activate Xdebug Helper (Mark `Debug`)
2. Go to PhpStorm and `Run > Start listening for PHP Debug Connections`
3. Put a breakpoint at your code
4. Refresh your page in Chrome (or go to another one, just make a request).

Basically, the Xdebug Helper will be your trigger. If you disable it, PhpStorm no longer will debug your code.

---

If you don't want to relay on an extension, you can go to your Xdebug config and set:

```
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

And "Start listening for PHP Debug Connections" will be your trigger.