# How can I get Xdebug working in PHPStorm with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I'm following the Laracast for PHPStorm and setting up xdebug. When I run xdebug on a controller in my laravel project, it prompts me to install a chrome extension. If I install said chrome extension, I just get a browser window stating Fatal Error: Class 'BaseController' not found . Jeff doesn't mention this extension, nor does anyone in the comments. As a result, I'm not seeing anything in the debugger except "Connected to JetBrains Chrome Extension". What gives? I followed the tutorial precisely.

Comment: Although it's not a complete answer like you need, check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527954/how-to-debug-code-while-using-my-browser-on-phpstorm/29541831#29541831) that I gave today may help you.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do JavaScript debug and not PHP. Make sure you are using correct "Debug" option (look at icons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow this jetbrains [guide](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) plus proxying tunneling the 9000 port.

For me Proxying / Tunneling the Debugger Connection do the trick.

I need to bring port 9000 to my local machine like this:

```
ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 vagrant@192.168.50.10  //or wathever ip of you homestead
```

instead of run `homestead sh` for login to my homestead machine.

I hope works for you.